# Работа с методом ReplyKeyboardHide. Ошибка AttributeError

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

На данный момент у меня есть задача показать клавиатуру телеграм бота, а потом - после нажатия кнопки "/stop" - убрать ее. 
Я написал такой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])

def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, config.LIST)
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    user_markup.row("/start","/stop")
    user_markup.row("bt1","bt2")
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Добро пожаловать.." , reply_markup=user_markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["stop"])

def stop(message):
    hide_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardHide()
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, reply_markup=hide_markup)
```

После запуска в консоли выдается ошибка "AttributeError: module 'telebot.types' has no attribute 'ReplyKeyboardHide' "
Я пошел в документацию телеграма Bot API и, вроде, сделал все так как там написано. 
В чем проблема и как исправить?

Comment: Объект называется [ReplyKeyboardRemove](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove).

Answer (score 0):

после создания клавиатуры добавь эту переменную и клава скроется после нажатия на кнопку

```
user_markup.one_time_keyboard = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hide_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
```

Код видимо поменялся с тех пор. Работает, если исправить на выше написанное.